# Obtaining information from Firebase: Swift

Tags: swift

I query a branch from Firebase, to get the following printed out to the console:

```
{
    2345 = 1;
    6244 = 1;
    q6x8 = 1;
}
```

I am trying to create an array of the values to the left; namely, an array which looks like: [2345, 6244, q6x8].

Because the data structure printed out to the console uses equal signs instead of colons, it is not a dictionary, nor a hash map. Thus, when I try to do

```
print(snap.value![0])
```

or

```
print(snap.value!.first)
```

I get an error saying "Type 'Any' has no subscript members" or "Type 'Any' has no member 'first'."

I am stuck. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your database look like?

Answer (score 0):

snap.value[0] doesn't work because the returned data is of type DataSnapshot. Also, Firebase uses key-value pair. So, your data must be something like: `2345 = 1 : true`

```
guard let snap = snap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}

for (key, val) in snap {
   print(key, val)
}
```

Answer varies by your Firebase data structure. In your case the `snap` is `2345 = 1 : true`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I get an error saying "Expression type '[DataSnapshot]' is ambiguous without more context" on the first for loop line. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be because your data structure is different. Can you post how your firebase structure looks like? Here is the idea tho: lets say you have            "{
    2345 = 1;
    6244 = 1;
    q6x8 = 1;
}" under a Firebase generated key. Then you should go the key endpoint and cast the value as array of DataSnapshot;

Answer (score 0):

Arjun,

I am accessing a dataset that is a database on firebase, my code looks like this.

```
typealias JSONObject = [String: Any]


Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: "blah.blah@gmail.com", password: "blahblah", completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            self.loadconfig(login: "blahblah", passwd:  "blahblah", rulelist: "blah")
        }
    })

..
..
..

 func loadconfig(login: String, passwd: String, rulelist:String) {

 let rootRef = Database.database().reference().child(rulelist)
 var jsonObjects:[JSONObject] = []
 rootRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        if let _ = snapshot.value as? [JSONObject] {
            jsonObjects = (snapshot.value as? [JSONObject])!
            do {
                self.products = try jsonObjects.map(decode)
            } catch {
                print("failed")
            }
        }
 }
```

And my data looks like this ...

```
{
"blah" : [ {
"X" : 1,
"Y" : 1,
"Z" : "true",
"A" : 1,
"B" : "https:",
}, {
"X" : "Rule 0",
"Y" : "Go Market after GrandHall",
"Z" : "00:01",
"A" : "true"
} ]
}
```

If this doesn't help try updating your question and include an export of your dataset in the question.